# Как взять и использовать элемент на который кликнули?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Сейчас решаю оду задачу и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

При клике на определенные картинки, они должны перемещаться в  некоторую область аимированно. Метод animate() знаю.

Проблема такая: мне нужно знать **на какую картинку кликнул пользователь** и ее перемещать, а после я должен использовать id или еще что-нибудь этой картинки, **для записи в переменную**.

Например, на картинку "камень" кликнули, я записываю в переменную userChoice = "камень". Я буду далее использовать эту переменную для сравнения уже в другой функции.

Comment: Для привязки произвольных данных к элементам разметки, существуют, например, data-атрибуты (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). Как их использовать в вашем конкретном случае, зависит от вашего же кода, который вы, почему то, не привели.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитайте про событийную модель в JS, а вот пока простой код

```
function getId (el) { 
   alert(el.id);
}
```

Ф-ция выводи id, да, аттрибут id находится в htmlобъекте, как обычное свойство
Как использовать

```
<img id='img' onclick='getId(this)'>
```

или прям из скрипта

```
var img; // ссылка на нашу картинку
img.onclick = function () {
    getId(img);
}
```

Код притянут за уши, но думаю вы поняли, о чем я

Comment: не совсем то, я нашел решение, спасибо за уделенное время